# How to move attributes above product tabs

Tags: magento2

With this code:

```
<move element="product.attributes" destination="content" after="-" />
```

Attributes moved under product tabs.
https://prnt.sc/_6gXFtYisOXC

Can anyone have solution how to move above this tabs? :)

Answer (score 1):

Try below code in your `catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<move element="product.attributes" destination="content" before="product.info.overview" />
```

Comment: after cache flush position not changed.  (other changes load correct because I do some more customizaiton) but in this case position not change.

Comment: now it's depend on your element. you already did lot of changes so I can't identify after or before which element you should put it.